# what's the steps can i follow to develop module for send notification from CMS OP to windows phone application?

Tags: plugin-development, php

i want to develop a windows phone application and receive notification from my CMS opencart 
So to send notification from my CMS, i must develop a module !

what's the steps can i follow to develop module for send notification from CMS OP to windows phone application?

Comment: Hi Ghali, welcome to Craft Stack Exchange. This question is far too broad to be answered in this format, so it will be closed. I've provided the best answer I can with the broad information provided... Feel free to post again when you have a much more **specific** question.

Comment: to send notification from my CMS OP to my windowsphone application that some one by something ! i must deveopp by php and xml to send informations ??

Comment: Again, still way too broad. What have you tried so far? Do you have any code examples of your current attempt? Take a look around Stack Exchange, you'll find most folks are asking **very specific** questions. If this is simply a topic for general discussion, I'd recommend brainstorming over at the [Google+ Community page](https://plus.google.com/communities/106505340287442511226).

Comment: In all honesty, it's not entirely clear that you're even using Craft as your CMS. You've tagged this question with "php" and "cms".

Comment: the code of the plugin is by php and xml !

Comment: i made my research ,to send notification to the app so what's the role of xml and php?

Answer (score 3):

An incredibly broad question deserves an incredibly broad answer... You'll need to build a plugin:

> http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction

(Apologies for the snarkiness)

Comment: You get an upvote for the snark.